# output both attribute name and attribute value in html tag with xslt variable

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have to put microdata (schema.org) in html tag like this:

```
<div class="list_item" itemtype="http://schema.org/Hotel" itemscope="itemscope">
```

I want to place all microdata stuff in one variable like this:

```
<xsl:param name="schema_main">
      <xsl:choose>

           <xsl:when test="$list_type = 'hotels'">
                <xsl:text>itemtype="http://schema.org/Hotel" itemscope="itemscope"</xsl:text>
           </xsl:when>

           <xsl:when test="$list_type = 'sight'">
                <xsl:text>itemtype="http://schema.org/CivicStructure" itemscope="itemscope"</xsl:text>
           </xsl:when>

       </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:param>
```

Bu I can't do it because I have to specify the attribute name in xslt to put any content:

```
 <div class="list_item" itmescope="{$some_variable}">
```

So the question is - can I put the string with both attribute name and attribute value in html tag with xslt? Something like:

```
<div class="list_item" $variable_with_attribute_name_and_attribute_value>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can use parameters in the way you describe. But if the objective is to remove repetitive coding, you could possible achieve this by means of a named template instead of a variable.

For example, here is a named template

```
   <xsl:template name="schema_main">
      <xsl:attribute name="itemtype">
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$list_type = 'hotels'">
               <xsl:text>http://schema.org/Hotel</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$list_type = 'sight'">
               <xsl:text>http://schema.org/CivicStructure</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
         </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="itemscope">itemscope</xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:template>
```

And to call it, to add attributes to the current element, you would just do this

```
  <div>
     <xsl:call-template name="schema_main"/>
  </div>
```

And then the output would be as follows:

```
<div itemtype="http://schema.org/Hotel" itemscope="itemscope" />
```

This is assuming you have set **list_type** to hotels. Note, it possible to pass parameters to the named template, should the **list_type** not be global in scope.

Answer (score 1):

**This can be done in a very simple way -- no `<xsl:choose>` / `<xsl:when>` and no `<xsl:call-template>`is used**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:param name="list_type" select="'BB'"/>

 <my:Schemas>
  <schema type="Hotel" aka="hotels"/>
  <schema type="CivicStructure" aka="sight"/>
  <schema type="BreadAndBreakfast" aka="BB"/>
 </my:Schemas>

 <xsl:variable name="vSchemas" select=
              "document('')/*/my:Schemas/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <div class="list_item"
         itemtype="http://schema.org/{$vSchemas[@aka=$list_type]/@type}"
         itemscope="itemscope"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied to any XML document (not used in this example), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<div class="list_item" itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadAndBreakfast"
                       itemscope="itemscope"/>
```

**Note**: The `<my:Schemas>` element will typically be passed as an external parameter to the transformation, and in this case it would be referenced directly, without the `document()` function.

Comment: @tylik: You are welcome. THis solution, actually is the "canonical" one :)

Comment: @Dimitre: I think you need to check a dictionary for the meaning of 'canonical'. Your answer is no more or less valid than the accepted one.

Comment: @Flynn1179: Many concepts or procedures had not been canonical for some time before they became canonical. It is my opinion that avoiding explicit conditionals may be a good candidate for "canonical" XSLT style. Experts in the field actively advocate for this style.

Comment: @Dimitre: I'm not an expert in XSLT, just a novice. But your answer opens some new perspectieves for me! At first I thought it was more complicated, but after a while I got the point.